# Reflexive Pronoun usage

Tags: word-choice

I'm a little confused. At work I often hear 'You can get in touch with **ourselves**' instead of 'Get in touch with **us**' and it triggers my inner toff.

Am I right in thinking that 'get in touch with ourselves' is an incorrect usage of a reflexive pronoun in this context?

Comment: Reflexive pronouns, as far as I know, should only be used when referring to something the pronoun was doing to itself. For example, "Sometimes I talk to myself" is fine, but "You can call myself on this number" isn't because someone else is doing the calling. On a similar note, "we can get in touch with ourselves" but you can't.

Comment: Despite the usage note that Edwin Ashworth mentions, such usage is not part of my AmE dialect and it sounds terrible to me.

Answer (score 3):

> If you have no success with the contacts you've mentioned, you can get
>   in touch with ourselves

is arguably grammatical and idiomatic, but uses 'ourselves' as an emphatic rather than a reflexive pronoun. [This article at GrammarMonster](http://grammar-monster.com/glossary/emphatic_pronouns.htm) explains what emphatic pronouns are and how they are usually used.

As to the particular usage here, without an accompanying personal pronoun or noun, a usage note at [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/myself) reads:

> Usage Note: The -self pronouns, such as myself, yourselves, and
>   herself, are sometimes used as emphatic substitutes for personal
>   pronouns, as in
>
> *He was an enthusiastic fisherman like myself.*
>
> The practice is particularly common in compound phrases:
>
> *The boss asked John and myself to give a brief presentation.*
>
> Although these usages have been common in the writing of reputable
>   authors for several centuries, they may not sit well with many readers
>   today. A majority of the Usage Panel dislikes them, though resistance
>   has been eroding over the years.

[An article by Ben Zimmer at Visual Thesaurus](http://www.visualthesaurus.com/cm/wordroutes/more-musings-on-myself/) contains:

> Part of the problem is that *myself* gets plugged in as a replacement
>   for *I* or *me* in many different ways, and people's judgments of
>   their acceptability may vary widely....
>
> You can judge for yourself which uses of *myself* sound acceptable or
>   unacceptable, and which fall in a gray area somewhere in between.
>   Personally, I don't mind myself too much when it appears at the end of
>   a list of names, as in Safire's "Price, Buchanan, and myself" or
>   Boswell's "Sir Joshua Reynolds, Dr. Burney, Dr. Johnson, and myself."
>   (Linguists call these "coordinate structures.") It also sounds
>   relatively fine to me when the speaker or writer is making a
>   comparison to someone or something else, especially after *than*, as
>   when John McCain speaks of "serving a cause greater than myself."

Personally, I find *He was an enthusiastic fisherman like myself.*  totally acceptable, and the first sentence in this answer at least as good as the 'with us' version (I feel emphasis is required to mark the unexpected suggested alternative).

However, using 'get in touch with ourselves' where the unmarked 'get in touch with us' is required is ridiculously bombastic:

> */?? 'We are Scan-Tecs. You can get in touch with ourselves in the following ways: ...'

Comment: Would it really be considered an emphatic in that position, Edwin? I get that in something like "We ourselves can be contacted at [number]" but in this context the pronoun doesn't appear to be emphasising who you can get in touch with, which would make it a reflexive pronoun being used improperly.

Comment: Yes. 'As a last resource, you can even get in touch with ourselves, though we don't usually deal direct with the public.'

Comment: The Grammar Monster examples looked like perfectly regular reflexives to me, albeit used for the purposes of emphasis. I didn't see any of the *please get in touch with ourselves* genre.

Comment: @WS2 She cut herself. <=/=> *She herself cut. Reflexive usage. // She went there herself.  <==> She herself went there. Central emphatic usage. // At last I've found another spin-bowler like myself. Disputed emphatic usage. [Ben Zimmer at Visual Thesaurus](http://www.visualthesaurus.com/cm/wordroutes/more-musings-on-myself/) has a balanced article.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth *She went there herself* is fine, but *he goes there with herself* sounds odd.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth +1 Very often, grammars regard *X-self* as emphatic when it is an adjunct, and as an override when a complement of a verb or preposition. But it depends on which grammar you're reading.

Comment: @Lawrence I'd say unacceptable (except as a tongue-in-cheek usage, with 'herself' used mockingly almost as a title, = 'her _Ladyship_'). This is in line with what Zimmer says:   'Part of the problem is that _[her]self_ gets plugged in as a replacement for [her] in many different ways, and people's judgments of their acceptability may vary widely....

You can judge for yourself which uses of myself [/herself ...] sound acceptable or unacceptable.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Agreed. My point was that even in the case where *[her]self* replaces the simple *[her]*, it's only valid when 'referenced' to herself (I'm not sure how to word the last part). The OP's sample of *you can get in touch with ourselves* sounds odd because *ourselves* is 'referenced' to *you*. Most of the examples in the links you provided don't address this issue of being 'referenced' to someone else.

Comment: @Lawrence ?: He was an enthusiastic fisherman like myself. /  The boss asked John and myself to give a brief presentation.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No, an emphatic use would be *us ourselves*: a reflexive can be used for emphasis, but that is **in addition to** the normal pronoun, not instead of it.

Comment: @Andrew Leach I've provided the AHDEL article in support of 'emphatic usage'. You haven't offered support for your stance.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Those look ok. I can't put my finger on it at the moment, but *you ask ourselves* seems to have a different quality from [both](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/316930/reflexive-pronoun-usage/316933?noredirect=1#comment720321_316933) your examples.

Comment: @Lawrence (1) Those examples 'address this issue of being 'referenced' to someone else' as you put it. (2) 'you ask ourselves' has insufficient context. I'd not worry about using 'If all your usual contractors are unable to help you, we suggest you ask ourselves' but **I'd not use** 'You ask ourselves to help, but then you refuse to let ourselves in your factory'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth On (1), yes, that's why I mentioned that I couldn't put my finger on it. Your examples work despite the external 'reference', so I expect there's some other factor involved. On (2), that's interesting. I'd place the fluency/awkwardness of the OP's original between your new pair of examples. Can you identify what's different about the factory example that makes it unacceptable?

Comment: @Lawrence Splitting hairs is child's play compared with explaining the idiosyncracies of idiomatic usage. Plaiting tinned milk is.

Answer (score 0):

Reflexives have two main uses: one where they function as **complement**, and an **emphatic** use where they function as modifier or adjunct:

*We said ourselves that you could get in touch*. (complement)

*We ourselves said that you could get in touch*. (emphatic)

The use of the reflexive pronoun in those example may be considered the default or normal form.

By contrast, the default form of a pronoun in examples like yours is non-reflexive, but you can **override** it by using a reflexive pronoun.

*We said you could get in touch with us* (default - non-reflexive pronoun)

*You can get in touch with ourselves*. (override with reflexive pronoun)

Grammatically, override reflexives do not require the close structural link between pronoun and antecedent that characterises basic reflexives. In fact, they can sometimes occur without any antecedent at all where the pronoun is interpreted in a purely deictic way, as in your example.

Comment: Not my downvote; this is CGEL treatment, if I remember it correctly. Largely just different terminology, though the 'override' concept is nice. Perhaps someone doesn't appreciate your not going into detail about when such overrides are acceptable, and to what degree (I've gone an extra inch or two). Though as Zimmer says, that's very close to being POB in many cases, and it would take a thesis to cover reasonably.

Comment: @BillJ +1 ... But "*We said ourselves that you could get in touch. (complement)*" <-- Isn't that an emphatic usage? I think a complement might be something like "We told ourselves that you could get in touch". In the original example *ourselves* seems like a reiteration of *we*. No?

Comment: @ Araucaria I'm inclined to think a more likely example would be _We blame ourselves for your not getting in touch_. "Ourselves" seems somewhat restrictive in its distribution compared to the other persons. I tried to work it into the OP's example with a minimum change of words, but lost the plot!